# internal hub gear

Tags: internally-geared-hub

Quick question. I can't change gear with a shifter, I suppose the gear cable might be an explanation. I don't have skills to repair that myself. It's stuck in high gear and I just want to lower it. Is there a possiblity to change gear manually? If yes, how?

Comment: There are several hub gears out there, all with their own foibles - can you provide a few more details, e.g. speeds, make and model. Plus an idea as to what has gone on with the shifter + cable?

Comment: Yeah, brand and model, PLEASE! Is it a Rohloff, a Shimano, an old Sturmey Archer? How many gears it has? Three, seven, nine, fourteen? Details!

Answer (score 2):

Very generally speaking, the hub is operated by a cable that pulls on a rod sticking out of the center of the hub.  If you can figure out what adjustment makes that rod go in and out you can change the gear (assuming it's not the hub itself that is frozen and not allowing a gear change).  But you need to get the adjustment right, since, for some hub styles, being "between" gears is bad.